# Is Orb an appropriate algorithm to identify heads in a video game

Tags: opencv, image-processing, orb

I am using orb to identify the head of sprites in a still from a video game. When I first read about the algorithm is seemed like a great fit for my purpose. However, it doesn't seem to be preforming as I expected and I don't have the intuition or experience to know whether or not this is a poorly chosen algorithm or if it's not working due to my implementation.
Here's my reference image:
[image]

And here is the image I'm searching within:
[image]

Here's the code I'm using (top image is img1, second image is  img2):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv.imread('6.jpg',0)
img2 = cv.imread('0.jpg',0)
# Initiate ORB detector
orb = cv.ORB_create(nfeatures=1000,WTA_K =3,scoreType=cv.ORB_FAST_SCORE,patchSize=10,edgeThreshold=50)
# find the keypoints with ORB
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# create BFMatcher object
bf = cv.BFMatcher(cv.NORM_HAMMING2, crossCheck=True)
# Match descriptors.
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)
# Sort them in the order of their distance.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
# Draw first x matches.
print(len(matches))
img3 = cv.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:200],None, flags=2)
plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

Now i understand that Orb wont work well for the sprites that are facing away from the camera, since the eyes/mouth wont be present (once I get this working I plan on running multiple reference images from different positions around the head), but I can't work out why it isn't matching some of the heads. Here's the print of all 74 matches it finds:
[image]

Although a few of the lines connect to the head of one of the sprites, they don't actually track from on feature of the original image to the same feature of the sprite (eg. tracks from eye of img1 to top of head in img2). What can I do to improve matches here?

Comment: If there's any more information that would be useful, please ask!

Comment: as you can see, the orb features are detected mostly in the eye region of the mask. But in your full image there is much less detail and often the eyes aren't visible at all. You can give machine learning like cascade classifier, hog detector and convolutional neural networks a chance, but you will have to prepare a lot of  training data.

Comment: ah, you could still try ORB , but you'll need more different tenplate images from all perspective variations and some scales. ORB and other keypoints descriptors are invariant to some transformatiobs, but typically only up to some degree of 2D transformation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to point out the problems I can notice first, the provide possible solutions and alternatives.

**Problems**

1. Scale Invariance: Although ORB uses image pyramids for scale invariance, it is not so robust. As you can see your 'train' image is bigger than the blobs of head you're trying to notice.
2. Background Noise: As you can see from your output, a lot of features(key-points) that are detected from the background are matching with your image. This is causing your code to return many inaccurate matches.
3. Alternate Cases: In the test image shown, the faces of the characters are, to a certain degree, rotated versions of your 'train' image. There can be many situations in which that is not so. ORB is rotation independent but that is for shapes that do not change so much with rotation. Incase a character was facing the camera directly, ORB and most key-point detection techniques would fail.

**Possible Solutions**

1. Use a scale invariant algorithm: SIFT is one option provided you're using this algorithm for non commercial purposes as it is patent protected in the USA. It is scale-invariant and in most cases, more accurate than ORB. The only tradeoff is the speed. Assuming you're using KNN to match points, reducing the distance ratio would also remove many outliers. Getting rid of the text is also going to help.
2. Determining regions of interest: To remove background noise, you can use contouring techniques to extract 'a box' around the character's body and then apply your algorithm so as to avoid matching with any key-points of the background. Another technique is an outlier removal algorithm called RANSAC(Random Sample Consensus)
3. Get enough images of characters facing in different directions and use each of them as a reference. This would be computationally expensive because you'll have to run your code multiple times on the same test image using different training 'heads'

**Alternatives**

Since you're looking for a very specific object, try training a CNN model. There are many readily available codes online that allow you to use your own training data. You could also try template matching. MSTM would be an example.